# How do you use the "%" operator in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operators

I have to take a number of days and convert them into weeks and days.

I know I have to use the `%` operator, but how do I use it?

Answer (score 3):

% is the modulo (remainder) operator. In your case, try:

```
int weeks = total_days / 7;
int remaining_days = total_days % 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

Odd how when people asking a question say "I know", they're often wrong.  You don't *need* modulus (`%`) at all.

```
int weeks = total_days / 7;
printf("%d days is equal to %d weeks and %d days.\n",
       total_days, weeks, total_days - weeks*7);
```

Comment: Although it's simpler and faster to use modulus.

Comment: @TheBigO, simpler maybe, but modulus implementations use the same formula internally, and would probably repeat the divide by 7 as well unless the compiler optimization is really good.

Comment: @Karl: Some CPUs can find both quotient and remainder with a single instruction.  But here is division by a constant, so if the compiler optimization is any good, it will calculate `weeks` using multiplication by a magic number and a bit shift, and no integer division will be needed anywhere.  @TheBigO: The compiler may very well optimize `total_days % 7` into the same code.  My main purpose with not using modulo is to challenge the question asker to think about the problem, and also tell us if use of modulo is a homework requirement or simply "what he heard was needed".

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can divide the total number of days by 7 and you will get the weeks.
THen you can perform modulo on total number of days with 7 and you get the days remaining.
Is this not enough

Answer (score 0):

% (modulus operator) gives you the remainder.  So days % 7 will give you the amount of days left after converting to weeks.  i.e. if days = 15, then days % 7 would equal 1.